# error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola estoy intentando capturar una variable en un componente hijo y pasarlo al componente padre App.js para actualizar el estado montoTotal. Este es el mensaje de error:

"Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

A continuación pongo los componentes que interactuan en el proceso:

App.js

```
  class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
   categorias: {},
   productos: {},
   productosOrden: {},
   orden: {},
   total: 0,
   montoTotal: 0};
   }
   totalMonto = (valor) =>{
     console.log(valor);
    const montoTotal = valor;
     this.setState({montoTotal});
     }

 render() {
   return (
    <div className="App">
    <div className="row">

      <PedidoTotal 
      {...this.state}
      titulo="Pedido Total" 
      totalMonto={this.totalMonto} 
      />
      <CalcularVuelto titulo="Calcule el Cambio"
      totalMonto={this.totalMonto} 
      />
    </div>
  </div>  
);}
```

-----componente PedidoTotal

```
 class PedidoTotal extends Component{
 renderOrden = (key) =>{
 const productos = this.props.productosOrden;
 console.log(productos);
 const prod = this.props.productosOrden[key];
 const count = this.props.orden[key];
 //this.props.actualizarMonto();
 return <li key={key}>
 {count}: unidades de {prod.nombre}
 :${count * prod.precio}
 <button onClick={()=>this.props.deleteOrden(key)}>eliminar</button>
 <button onClick={()=>this.props.reduceOrden(key)}>Reducir</button>
 </li>
 }
 render(){
    const ordenIds = Object.keys(this.props.orden);
    //Calculando el total a pagar
      const total = ordenIds.reduce((prevTotal, key)=>{
        const prod = this.props.productosOrden[key];
        const count = this.props.orden[key];
        return prevTotal + (count * prod.precio)
    }, 0);
    this.props.totalMonto(total);  
    return(
    <div className="col-md-3">
        <h3>{this.props.titulo}</h3>
        <ul>
            {ordenIds.map(this.renderOrden)}
        </ul>
        <h5>Total a pagar: ${total} </h5>
    </div>
    );
   }
  }
```

Comment: Esto se origina cuando generas un bucleinf en el render,

Comment: gracias Luciano realmente me puse a revisar bien y me di cuenta de eso. Lo solucione agregando estas lineas a la funcion totalMonto y quedo asi:   totalMonto = () =>{
      const ordenIds = Object.keys(this.state.orden);
    //Calculando el total a pagar
      const total = ordenIds.reduce((prevTotal, key)=>{
      const prod = this.state.productosOrden[key];
      const count = this.state.orden[key];
      return prevTotal + (count * prod.precio)
    }, 0);
      console.log(total);
     return total; 
  }

Comment: Puedes poner tu código como respuesta a la pregunta y aceptarla así no se pierde en los comentarios

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigos la respuesta a mi problema fue implementar el calculo del monto total a pagar en la misma función totalMonto y asi evite el bucleif:

```
totalMonto = () =>{
  const ordenIds = Object.keys(this.state.orden);
//Calculando el total a pagar
  const total = ordenIds.reduce((prevTotal, key)=>{
  const prod = this.state.productosOrden[key];
  const count = this.state.orden[key];
  return prevTotal + (count * prod.precio)
  }, 0);
  console.log(total);
 return total; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que no te vuelva a suceder esto y cabe mencionar lo siguiente.

Nunca debes mutar el estado dentro de la función render, la razón es porque la función render se ejecuta automáticamente en estos tres escenarios:

1. El estado/state a sido mutado utilizando la función .setState() del
   componente.
2. Las propiedades/props han sido mutadas por un componente en un jerarquía superior
3. Invocando la función .forceUpdate() del componente, esto provoca que el componente se vuelva a renderizar sin importar que no exista una mutación en el state o props.

De modo que si por alguna razón mutas el estado dentro de la función render(), estas provocando una segunda ejecución de dicha función y esta a su vez llevará una tercera llamada y así consecutivamente provocando un bucle infinito.

Eso es exactamente lo que estas haciendo en el componente `PedidoTotal` pero en tu caso el bucle infinito se da por una combinación del primer y segundo escenario.

Tu jerarquia de componentes es

```
App
  -> PedidoTotal
```

Tu bucle se produce cuando en la función render del componente `PedidoTotal` ejecutas la siguiente linea `this.props.totalMonto(total)`, donde `totalMonto` es una función del componente superior `App` que tu la expones al componente del nivel jerárquico inferior a través de `props`, en la implementación de esta función es donde esta el problema.

```
totalMonto = (valor) =>{
    console.log(valor);
    const montoTotal = valor;
    this.setState({montoTotal});
}
```

y es que estas mutando el estado en la linea final al invocar `this.setState({montoTotal});` esto provocara que el estado de `App` mute y por lo tanto ejecute la función `render` del componente `App` lo que a su vez provocara que se vuelva a ejecutar la función `render` del componente `PedidoTotal` y asi sucesivamente llevando a un bucle infinito.

```
PedidoTotal.render() -> App.totalMonto() -> App.render() -> PedidoTotal.Render() -> App.totalMonto() -> App.render() -> PedidoTotal.render() -> App.totalMonto() -> App.render()... etc.
```

Lo que solucionó tu problema en realidad fue que posteriormente eliminaste la linea `this.setState({montoTotal});` de la función `totalMonto` del componente `App`, al hacerlo rompiste el bucle infinito solucionando el problema.